# What needs to be done to cleanly move a Bugzilla installation from one server to another?

Tags: migration, bugzilla

I have the most recent version of Bugzilla running on one server, and need to migrate it to another. What steps need to be taken to cleanly move Bugzilla to another host? Minimal downtime is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the instructions here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Move_Installation